# Ruby on Rails create action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am fairly new to Ruby. I am trying to follow along with a tutorial for creating a simple posting app.

My create action will not work. I tried this and it seems to do something in the terminal, but it doesn't add it to my Posts object.

Here is my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create 
    @post = Post.new(:title => params[:title], :content => params[:content])
    @post.save  
  end

  def edit 
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy 
  end
end
```

Here is my new view:

```
<h1>Add a New Post</h1>

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Add a New Post" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This is what comes up in the terminal when I try to submit:

```
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2016-08-31 17:54:39 -0700
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (16.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM         "schema_migrations"
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"tGpevHtpEoP5jHYqCn1G7tUKX9YWnx+PWkqlPzKadTCiIEX1UGs96mSCrDf  UIShKjp+ObwNA6G1nh3KE5gAIgw==", "post"=>{"title"=>"Jack's Post",  "content"=>"Please use this post"}, "commit"=>"Add a New Post"}
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (16.0ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)    [["created_at", 2016-09-01 00:54:40 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-09-01 00:54:40 UTC]]
(14.7ms)  commit transaction
No template found for PostsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 114ms (ActiveRecord: 31.3ms)
```

I feel like I've read about a million stack overflow posts about this and no one seems to have the answer. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've successfully inserted a record into the database. What do you want to happen next? How about:

```
redirect_to action: 'index'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use strong params to get the parameters you need from the form.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
  end

private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    # params.require(:post).permit! # Allow all
  end

end
```

If you want your exisiting solution to work, you would need to prefix the params like this:

```
@post = Post.new(:title => params[:post][:title], :content => params[:post][:content])
```

If you examine the logs, you'll see the form input is nested inside of `post`

```
"post"=>{"title"=>"Jack's Post",  "content"=>"Please use this post"}
```

Comment: Strong parameters may not be covered by the tutorial that the OP is following. I hadn't heard of them (I'm still on Rails 3.x). Go easy!

Comment: That is why I provided both solutions. :) @MickSharpe

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I'm not entirely sure I understand why this does what it does, but I'm sure as I keep going I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you look in the logs it clearly says that I have rendered no view.

```
No template found for PostsController#create, rendering head :no_content
```

So in `PostsController#create` action we need to redirect to any action, mostly we redirect to show action. So you need add following line in create action.

```
# redirects user to show page of newly created post.
if @post.save
 redirect_to @post
else
 render 'new'
end
```

Go kill waves :)